# Cannot instantiate abstract class using C++ interface for CLR

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I am trying to implement a C++ interface for mscorlib::_Assembly (mscorlib.tlb), but I'm running into trouble with the IDispatch class which _Assembly requires.

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2966): error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject<CIAssembly>': cannot instantiate abstract class
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2966): note: due to following members:
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2966): note: 'HRESULT mscorlib::_Assembly::GetType(mscorlib::_Type **)': is abstract
2>  c:\users\sruzin\source\_repos\gosecure\sensor\occultus\build\msbuild\bin\tmp\x64\umhook\release\mscorlib.tlh(14847): note: see declaration of 'mscorlib::_Assembly::GetType'
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2966): note: 'HRESULT mscorlib::_Assembly::GetName(mscorlib::_AssemblyName **)': is abstract
2>  c:\users\sruzin\source\_repos\gosecure\sensor\occultus\build\msbuild\bin\tmp\x64\umhook\release\mscorlib.tlh(14853): note: see declaration of 'mscorlib::_Assembly::GetName'
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2966): note: 'HRESULT mscorlib::_Assembly::GetName_2(VARIANT_BOOL,mscorlib::_AssemblyName **)': is abstract
```

I tried to declare the IDispatch methods as virtual and as pure virtual functions, none of this worked.

```
typedef mscorlib::_Assembly IAssembly;
class CIAssembly :
    IDispatchImpl<IAssembly>,
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>
    //public IDispatch,
    public IAssembly,
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>
{
private:
    CComPtr<CIAssembly>      obj;
    CComPtr<IUnknown>        objUnk;

public:
    CIAssembly(void)
    {

    }

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CIAssembly)
        //COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IAssembly)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE_BLIND(m_objUnk)
    END_COM_MAP()

    // Implemented by IDispatch or IUnknown
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount(__RPC__out UINT *pctinfo);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo(
        __in UINT iTInfo,
        __in LCID lcid,
        __RPC__deref_out_opt ITypeInfo **ppTInfo);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames(
        __RPC__in REFIID riid,
        __RPC__in_ecount_full(cNames) LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        __RPC__in_range(0, 16384) UINT cNames,
        __in LCID lcid,
        __RPC__out_ecount_full(cNames) DISPID *rgDispId);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(
        _In_  DISPID dispIdMember,
        _In_  REFIID riid,
        _In_  LCID lcid,
        _In_  WORD wFlags,
        _In_  DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
        _Out_opt_  VARIANT *pVarResult,
        _Out_opt_  EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,
        _Out_opt_  UINT *puArgErr);
```

I have also implemented the other functions required by _Assembly (I followed the function declarations in mscorlib.tlh). In class CIAssembly:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_ToString(
    __out BSTR * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Equals(
    __in VARIANT other,
    __out VARIANT_BOOL * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetHashCode(
    __out long * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetType(
    __out struct _Type * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_CodeBase(
    __out BSTR * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_EscapedCodeBase(
    __out BSTR * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetName(
    __out struct _AssemblyName * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetName_2(
    __in VARIANT_BOOL copiedName,
    __out struct _AssemblyName * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_FullName(
    __out BSTR * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_EntryPoint(
    __out struct _MethodInfo * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetType_2(
    __in BSTR name,
    __out struct _Type * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetType_3(
    __in BSTR name,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL throwOnError,
    __out struct _Type * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetExportedTypes(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypes(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetManifestResourceStream(
    __in struct _Type * Type,
    __in BSTR name,
    __out struct _Stream * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetManifestResourceStream_2(
    __in BSTR name,
    __out struct _Stream * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFile(
    __in BSTR name,
    __out struct _FileStream * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFiles(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFiles_2(
    __in VARIANT_BOOL getResourceModules,
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetManifestResourceNames(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetManifestResourceInfo(
    __in BSTR resourceName,
    __out struct _ManifestResourceInfo * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_Location(
    __out BSTR * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_Evidence(
    __out struct _Evidence * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCustomAttributes(
    __in struct _Type * attributeType,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL inherit,
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCustomAttributes_2(
    __in VARIANT_BOOL inherit,
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsDefined(
    __in struct _Type * attributeType,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL inherit,
    __out VARIANT_BOOL * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetObjectData(
    __in struct _SerializationInfo * info,
    __in mscorlib::StreamingContext Context);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE add_ModuleResolve(
    __in struct _ModuleResolveEventHandler * value);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE remove_ModuleResolve(
    __in struct _ModuleResolveEventHandler * value);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetType_4(
    __in BSTR name,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL throwOnError,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL ignoreCase,
    __out struct _Type * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSatelliteAssembly(
    __in struct _CultureInfo * culture,
    __out struct _Assembly * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSatelliteAssembly_2(
    __in struct _CultureInfo * culture,
    __in struct _Version * Version,
    __out struct _Assembly * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LoadModule(
    __in BSTR moduleName,
    __in SAFEARRAY * rawModule,
    __out struct _Module * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LoadModule_2(
    __in BSTR moduleName,
    __in SAFEARRAY * rawModule,
    __in SAFEARRAY * rawSymbolStore,
    __out struct _Module * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateInstance(
    __in BSTR typeName,
    __out VARIANT * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateInstance_2(
    __in BSTR typeName,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL ignoreCase,
    __out VARIANT * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateInstance_3(
    __in BSTR typeName,
    __in VARIANT_BOOL ignoreCase,
    __in enum BindingFlags bindingAttr,
    __in struct _IBinder * Binder,
    __in SAFEARRAY * args,
    __in struct _CultureInfo * culture,
    __in SAFEARRAY * activationAttributes,
    __out VARIANT * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLoadedModules(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLoadedModules_2(
    __in VARIANT_BOOL getResourceModules,
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetModules(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetModules_2(
    __in VARIANT_BOOL getResourceModules,
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetModule(
    __in BSTR name,
    __out struct _Module * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetReferencedAssemblies(
    __out SAFEARRAY * * pRetVal);
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_GlobalAssemblyCache(
    __out VARIANT_BOOL * pRetVal);
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your implementation? The problem is not with `IDispatch`, it is with `mscorlib::_Assembly` (aka `IAssembly`). Your `CIAssembly` class derives from `IAssembly` and needs to implement all of the abstract methods of `IAssembly`, but it is not doing that, which is why you are getting errors that your class is abstract.

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed, I have implemented the other functions as they were in the mscorlib.tlh header identically. In mscorlib.tlh _Assembly doesn't have any functions for IDispatch. Note: I have also used this method for other classes like ICorRuntimeHost which compiles successfully.

Comment: Well, clearly there is a mismatch somewhere, otherwise the compiler would not be complaining.

Comment: @RemyLebeau agreed, but is there a special way to declare the IDispatch functions within CIAssembly?

Comment: Why are you so focused on `IDispatch`? The errors you have shown have NOTHING to do with `IDispatch`, only with `mscorlib::_Assembly`.  Oh, and FYI, your `CIAssembly` class does not need to specify `public IAssembly` in its inheritance when also using `IDispatchImpl<IAssembly>`, since `IDispatchImpl<IAssembly>` derives from `IAssembly`, so `CIAssembly` will implicitly derive from `IAssembly` as well.